# How can I update my username in Chat?

Tags: support, chat

I previously used my name as my handle. I've managed to update it on the main site, but the change doesn't seem to reflect in chat.

I've sifted through meta posts with tags like [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) change/alter/edit/delete username for changing or deleting usernames, and they indicate there might be actions that affect the username, but it is not meant to explicitly change it like an account merge.

What are my options? I'm willing to consider everything from GDPR requests to nuking the accounts, but I want to be sure this will actually remove my name from chat.

Comment: How recently did you change it? did you change it network-wide? Chat consists of several separate servers, and your account changes sync to it periodically. You shouldn't need to do anything special other than wait (though a mod might be able to expedite it?)

Comment: Are you talking about at mentions in the comments / chat? Yeah, I don't believe there is a way to alter that directly. I don't know whether they handle that in GDPR but might be useful I guess. If the comments you are looking at aren't useful / aren't needed anymore just flag them as "No longer needed".

Comment: Oh, I do see your username being different in chat, it seems like chat profiles update in around an hour, try checking after that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95423/how-long-does-it-take-for-chat-profiles-to-update

Comment: I see your [chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/860947) with your updated name. Though caching is certainly in play here on many levels. If you are asking for chat messages and/or comments that contain your old username to be retroactively changed, that will not happen. If that is your request then I'd recommend using the [Contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to contact a staff member to see what options might be available to you.

Comment: Hmm, so when I mentioned I could see a different username for you in chat I was talking about the chat transcript. Seems like [messages in chat are attributed to the name of the author at the time the message was posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303923/old-display-name-is-still-visible-in-chat-transcript/303936#303936) If that is what you're looking at the contact form as mentioned by Henry Ecker seems to be your best choice.

Comment: Derp, please disregard my last comment, I checked the link Abdul posted and this is a feature, not a bug, and is working as designed. I guess I'll need to go the GDPR route cuz according to that post, it reads as if a nuke won't actually do anything.

Comment: @HenryEcker Do you know how long the turnaround for a GDPR request is? I submitted one yesterday, so not rushing, just want to see what the expectation should be.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know anything about the GDPR process for Stack Exchange so I couldn't even guess.